# Can you unzip an IPA package without either changing the extension or having admin rights?

Tags: macos, zip, ios

A colleague who I admin for has just asked me why, when he wants to unzip an IPA file, the GUI archive manager asks for an admin password when he tries to decompress an IPA that he has downloaded (his user is not an admin, so someone from ops has to come over if he wants to do this). His work around is to change the extension to zip first, then he is able to unzip the package without an admin password.

I haven't seen this before, and from a cursory google I see a couple of other similar posts recommending this workaround in the answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160863/how-to-re-sign-the-ipa-file

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975049/change-app-version-with-only-ipa-file-provided-no-xcode/16975145

Is there a way (other than using the command line unzip util) for a non admin user to unzip an ipa file? Do they have to be in a particular group for this to be allowed?